# Can't ssh into my node

Tags: ssh, jenkins

first, I'm doing this for past two days, but nothing works.

I've seen many tutorials, but no one works for me.

I have jenkins installed, in it I have Master node and I want to create new node. (some agent)

I want to establish connection with ssh.

I have jenkins user already on my new node and generated ssh key. 
(where is jenkins installed, there isn't jenkins user).

But the jenkins is telling me 'can't find known_hosts in /var/jenkins_home'. But this file exist.
I checked if port 22 is open on my new node, and yes, it is, I can connect to it from my local PC.

Is there some other method, but it should be with SSH, not agent.rar.

What should I check?

EDIT:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 24 17:36 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh

sudo -u jenkins ssh jenkins@*IP* ls -la .ssh
The authenticity of host '*IP* (*IP*)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:*FINGERPRINT*.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: What OS/Distro is this ?

Comment: On your Jenkins Master machine, could you run `sudo ls -la ~jenkins/.ssh` and add the output to your question.  Also could you try `sudo -u jenkins ssh jenkins@<nodehostname> ls -la .ssh` as Jenkins user on your Master host and also add the output to the question.

Comment: ubuntu 16 @user430214

Comment: @sborsky edited

Comment: in my ubuntu home folder, there's `.ssh/authorized_keys`. The `authorized_keys` file contains one or more keys. Also, the permissions you show are too open. The `authorized_keys` file should have `-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1224 Jun  1  2016 authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1):

You normally have the `.ssh` directory file permissions set as `700` and owned by the user who needs to access it.

As it is with `644` it's not going to be traversable by anyone (except root) so no wonder it can't be read by a user process. Change the ownership to jenkins and the perms to 700. Then set the ownership/permissions on the contents of the directory correctly too.

Then read up on Unix file and ownership permissions.

Comment: So I have to change owner to jenkins and set it to 700?

Comment: Permission denied (public key).

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins user's `.ssh` directory doesn't exist, instead some file with the same name. To fix this: Remove it, create the directory and set ownder and permissions.

```
rm ~jenkins/.ssh
install -d -o jenkins -m 0700 ~jenkins/.ssh
```

This will solve the `Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts` error.

Then copy your Jenkins SSH private and public keys into that directory and change there owner to `jenkins`, the mode for the private key to `0600` and for the public key `0644`.

Test again by running `sudo -u jenkins ssh jenkins@<nodehostname> ls -la .ssh`.

If it still fails, add the error message to your question.